What exqctly is the nuance of そのついで?
この恋が終わることは、この恋が始まらなかったことよりも、悲劇ではなかった。
たとえ、いつか消える春の夢だとしても。
この瞬間に、ハートを燃やして。
この目でシャッターを切って。
全力で笑って、全力で傷ついて、今を生きていく。
君の笑う、たった一秒を、見逃さずに。
永遠なら、そのついででいい。
This is a sentence that happens at the end of a novel. The narration is I guess reflecting on the relationship. I'm stumbled, what  is the exact nuance of "そのついで" here?
"I have have eternity/If our relationship/love is eternal".. "then it's fine"

ついで roughly means "secondary/extra purpose". ついでに is a very common expression. ～でいい means this. For example, ついででいい is used like this:

何かのついででいいので、この本を図書館に返してきてもらえる？
It's okay if it's a secondary purpose of something (else), so can you return this book to the library?
→ Can you return this book to the library when you happen to be going that way?

Similarly, 永遠ならそのついででいい suggests that "eternity" is merely an optional bonus. Read it as "Eternity? It's good if I can get it naturally, but it's not my primary concern". For this なら, see: Use of なら that are not "if"
This passage describes his momentary and ephemeral stance. Rather than worrying about the sustainability of the relationship, he is putting an extreme emphasis on "now".
